# Difference between manually creating a client proxy and referencing a MSMQ WCF service?

Tags: wcf, msmq, service-reference

In most examples of WCF services that use MSMQ transport it is always preferred to create a proxy manually using svcutil in Visual Studio command prompt rather than simply adding a Service Reference. When you can just reference the service by providing its endpoint address to the Add Service Reference dialog in visual studio why would you want to create a proxy with VS command prompt (since it is slightly more laborious)? I just came across this while reading [WCF 4 Step by Step](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145302403.do):

> Note that you cannot easily use the Add Service Reference Wizard in
>   Visual Studio to add a reference to a WCF service that uses the MSMQ
>   transport.

Why exactly is it difficult? What exactly is the benefit (if any) of the former method of referncing a WCF service? It seems to me that creating a proxy manually is just unnecessarily complicating the task.

Comment: I don't know what the difference would be, unless there's an issue with mex over msmq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pre-generate a proxy as long as you have a reference to the assemblies which define the service interface, operations, and data contracts. You can then create the proxy on the fly using ChannelFactory.

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyServiceInterface>("MyServiceNameInAppConfig");
var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
```

This is far simpler than using svcutil. However, if the service is remote and you cannot get access to the type assemblies then you have no other choice but to generate a proxy.

Regarding your question about why it's easier to use svcutil instead of VS to generate the proxy code, without seeing the actual book it is hard to comment, but under the hood visual studio uses svcutil to generate the code anyway, so I can't see how it would be any better or worse. When you do this manually then you have more control over what gets generated I guess.